# Android SDK Platform option cannot be ticked/selected in Android Studio Setup Wizard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have planned to install Android Studio on my new computer and i need to tick this component that I've mentioned in the title. But it cannot be selected, when i tick, just nothing happens and also the API 29: Android 10.0 (Q) is cannot be deselected/unticked. I need to use Android SDK Platform to install and work on Android 8.0 (Oreo). Anyone has a solution/idea for this issue? Thanks in advance for your interest. And you can see the problem in the imade below;

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gj1y.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles over this question again:

- Cancel the Android Studio Wizard.
- Choose to the option to restart the Wizard next time.
- You will end up in the Project Menu.
- Close Android Studio completely.

**Run Android Studio as Administrator (Windows).**

Did the trick for me. I should also mention that I purged practically all of Android from my Windows beforehand so in case running as Admin doesn't work out rightaway you might want to try a full uninstall and manually deleting all the files.